# Input a joints position in joint creation from different function Maya Python

Tags: python, maya

I want to input joint position (from different function) in joint creation, so I can assign it to another function

```
def joint_pos():
    cogPos = base.xform("jnt_cog", q=True, t=True, ws=True)
    L_armPos = base.xform("jnt_l_upperarm", q=True, t=True, ws=True)
    R_armPos = base.xform("jnt_r_upperarm", q=True, t=True, ws=True)
    L_thighPos = base.xform("jnt_l_thigh", q=True, t=True, ws=True)
    R_thighPos = base.xform("jnt_r_thigh", q=True, t=True, ws=True)
   return cogPos, L_armPos, R_armPos, L_thighPos, R_thighPos

def create_joint(name, position, side, suffix):
    joint_name = "{}_{}_{}_{}".format(name, position, side, suffix)
    joint = base.joint(radius=1, p=position, name=joint_name)
    return joint
```

i got an error invalid argument p=position. Any help or advice would be awesome, thanks!

Comment: Your code is incomplete. The create_joint() function cannot be executed because `base` is nod defined. Please update the code in a way we can copy and paste it. And please post the complete error message, it may help.